# Windows 10 File Explorer very slow, constantly processing, hanging & crashing. Tried to fix for years, many reinstalls. Do I need to upgrade?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

**I know this is a long post but only because I have taken great effort to fully describe the problem and that which I have tried to resolve the issue.** This problem exists on what is basically a server. It houses an AMD Ryzen 5 3600, 64 GB of RAM, and AsRock x570 Phantom Gaming X motherboard, a Samsung 990 Pro 2TB Nvme SSD for my C drive, all Seagate Exos drives for HHDs and even using Primocache with a  512 GB Samsung 970 EVO Plus as a cache for all my drives. I am running the latest version of Windows 10.

Basically, File Explorer has become very sketchy. It often hangs, becomes very slow, eventually crashing and restarting. When opening problem folders, they initially display no files, and slowly populates as a green status shading fills the address bar, sometimes taking over a minute. This usually occcurs with folders that either have large files, many files, or both, but also with folders that do not hold either. Explorer will also start hogging memory and often will start covering the taskbar when I have floating windows. When it is not doing any of the above, it often pauses when files or folders are accessed either with right or left clicks, giving me blue spinning rings, which last for milliseconds to over 10 seconds.

This has been occurring for over a year. I have tried many fixes, such as: Shutting down and restarting File Explorer, using different power settings, setting the hard drives never to sleep, rebuilding the indexes, turning windows search and indexing off and on, disabling the Windows Search Service, running several virus scans, performing an SFC scans (which produces no errors), running the Search and Indexing Troubleshooter (which also found no problems), and removing some possible problem columns, such as "Date" from displaying. I have also tried using the control panel>File Explorer Options to "Clear File Explorer Cache" and switched "Open File Explorer" to "This PC."

None of this improved the situation. The one thing that helped significantly was changing the customization tab under properties to general items.  Now, folders load somewhat better, and File Explorer does not crash nearly as much. Still I often  get a blue spinning ring while hovering over file explorer as it hangs for 5-20 seconds of time, even though nothing is happening: files are not being moved and no major processes are occurring in the background of which I am aware. Sometimes this happens when nothing is being copied or accessed at all. It is almost like the hard drive is waking from a sleep state even though I have hard drives never idling and I have accessed the drive in question just 5 minutes before. Sometimes the blue spinning ring just flickers as if the disk is busy, turning off and on repeatedly for seconds at a time while not allowing me to access the file. I do notice that sometimes when these pauses occur, I can hear a hard drive starting up, though often it is not the one I am accessing.

I have read countless articles, visited many forums and tried several support options, and no one can figure out what is going on. The worst thing is that this problem has persisted through at least 3-4 re-installs, 2 different machines and even though all my drives have probably been swapped out. I have checke the health of my drives regularly using chkdsk and HDSentinel, and they are all in good condition.

These problems do not seem to occur with Free Commander, though xyplorer does seem to hang as well, but that may be due to some of its settings. I know both programs perform searches much more efficiently than File Explorer.

I will say that I have LOTS of files and some of them very large and I have 10 internal HHD, 3 internal SSDs and I often have 1-3 USB Externals and sometimes so eSATA bays attached for backups.  I use this computer for all my media, including my extended family's photo archives with some large documents scanned at 1200 dpi with 48 bit color. I also have 25 terabytes of music and about 40 terabytes of movies.

I suspect may be asking too much of my build and am seriously considering upgrading to a w790 platform, maybe even using a w7 processor and 1 terabyte of memory. I am willing to do what I must to enjoy a responsive and stable system. I just don’t want to throw money away on upgrades I do not need for a server. I just need to access my files quickly and I can no longer afford to do all this waiting during these pauses in functionality.  I probably waste over an hour a day, if not more, waiting for things to load or just be accessible.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you are using 64-bit Apps for all shell context extension apps. That is how I solved this issue (a while back).

Comment: Does it matter if File Explorer is opening a path that is on a SSD or HDD? File Explorer crashing suggests an application modifying the shell, for instance something like Dropbox,

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode ?

Comment: Do you have all media mounted at all times? Any single one not present as the machine is slow? **Example:** Just recently I had slow disk access in a VMWare guest, that particular VM is not meant to ever access any network so no NIC enabled, but ENABLING a network interface (but not connecting to a network!) made a tremendous difference in Explorer/file access.

Comment: Thanks John, I will check into that.  I believe I do have some 32bit apps in there. I will report back.

Comment: Ramhound: This does not happen on the SSD, but there are no large files or folders with lots of files in them.  I do remember this occuring with a External SSD (WD Blue 4 TB) that did.

Comment: Harrymc: I have not tried booting into safe mode but will try in the coming days to see if that helps.

Comment: Hannu: I do not have any network drives attached.  Some of my USB drives are not always attached but they are not mapped.

Comment: @John What would be the most efficient way of checking this.  I am finding that there are a lot of items in my context menu and using Shell View and Shellex View I see I have more than I originally thought.  This looks like it can be quite messy and I am not sure how to determine which are 32 and which are 64 bit.

Comment: You need to look through your Apps, uninstall 32-bit versions and install 64-bit versions. Office and Adobe both should be 64-bit.  Sometimes starting again is the best way.